# Deriving first passage time from Gambler's ruin

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Quantity of interest: the first time a stochastic process hits a certain threshold $a\in \mathbb{R}$, if it starts at $0$:
$$T_a = \min\{ t>0: X_t = a  | X_0 = 0 \}$$

We are interested in the distribution of $T_a$ for either case,

1. a discrete-time stochastic process $X_t$ (called Gambler's ruin problem), or
2. a continuous-time, specifically a diffusion process $X_t$ given by $dX_t = adt + \sigma^2 dB_t$ (called first passage time).

**How can we derive 2. (continuous) from 1. (discrete)?**

I think it should be related to the derivation of continuous process from discrete processes with infinitesimal time step (i.e. the way Brownian motion is derived from random walk).